# JSTL cout is not working

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I have following script in my page ; **cout** tag is not returning any value...

```
<c:set var="simple.Var" value="simple.Var"></c:set>
<c:out value="${simple.Var}" ></c:out>
```

Please let me know where the problem is ?

Comment: Write only ${simple.var} without c:out - that will help :) And clarify whether your get method name is getVar? If not - do it with get prefix. Then use it in EL with lower case without prefix ${simple.var}.

Comment: @shved90 : That is also not working (without cout)

Comment: Does your page work except this block or does it throw any exception somewhere? You could try to set <%@page isELIgnored="false"%> , because by default it's true and your EL is ignored. Sometimes it helps. Or did you set bean or you used servlets?

Comment: Other possible scenario - that nothing was set, <c:set var="var" value="your_text_or_value"></c:set> and method inside Bean named setVar(String value). Lookout this small tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags

Comment: Logan can you please provide more information? We are obviously guessing here. E.g. are you getting any exceptions logged? What html content is being served?

Comment: @Muel : not expections at all... it prints nothing.. its empty output

Comment: You could print/log on the back-end part when setting or getting and check out whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `·` in the variable name. Change the variable name to `simpleVar` as follows:

```
<c:set var="simpleVar" value="simple.Var"/>
<c:out value="${simpleVar}"/>
```

**Edit...** shved90 makes a good point. If you have a bean in the request context named `simple` and that bean has a method `getVar()`, then all you need in the JSP is:

```
<c:out value="${simple.var}"/>
```

Comment: It could be a model or manager named simple, so it wouldn't help in this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

1-This is not a good variable name 
     
Do not use "." in variable name.

2-if you use

```
   <c:set var="simpleVar" value="simple.Var"/>
```

Without Using c:out, you can show simpleVar's value.

3-if you have a bean named simple and it has a property var( has a getVar() method) you can directly use simple.var without using any tag